# Ejabberd source code Installation in windows 10

Tags: ejabberd, ejabberd-module, ejabberd-saas

I want to know the procedure to install Ejabberd from source code in windows 10. In their documentation, the installation with source code is only given for the Linux based operating system. I am struggling to find any good documentation on the same.

Answer (score 0):

I think the windows installer is, in fact, compiled and packaged in Linux or other operating system. Following this reasoning, there's a way to get your self-compiled ejabberd running in Windows:

1. Download and install the latest ejabberd binary package in your Windows server. See what Erlang/OTP version and what ejabberd version you have.
2. Now, go to a development machine where you know ejabberd can be compiled: GNU/Linux, BSD, maybe Mac.
3. Download the same Erlang/OTP version, and download the source code of the same ejabberd version
4. Compile ejabberd
5. Copy the resulting *.beam files from the development machine to the Windows server, overwriting the originally installed ones